# aix unix 6.1 - 'find' command not executing via cronjob; but ok from shell

Tags: shell, unix, cron, aix

non-recursively find files older than 1 minute within my home directory and update their timestamp

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/find /home/me/ \( ! -name . -prune \) \( -type f -mmin +1 -name "*" \) -exec /usr/bin/touch {} \;
```

it runs like a charm from shell but not as a cronjob.

i've tried this modification:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/find /home/me/ \( ! -name . -prune \) \( -type f -mmin +1 -name "*" \) -exec /usr/bin/touch {} \\;
```

and this one:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/find /home/me/ \( ! -name . -prune \) \( -type f -mmin +1 -name "*" \) -exec /usr/bin/touch -- {} \;
```

still no joy.

avoiding a wrapper - a script to call this find command.

any ideas and pointers on how to make the cronjob work are appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting mail messages with errors.  I got this:

```
sh: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 1 : `(' is not expected.
```

So I doubled the \ to \\.  That might be working.  I'm not clear what the find command is suppose to be doing.

To debug this, I would prefix the command with a simple "echo" and then capture the output to a file.  Indeed, during debugging, I would add a -print and capture it to a file as well as stderr to a separate file until it was working.